# Asian seal identification (Characters identified: 文景)

Tags: character-identification, seal

I inherited this painting from my grandfather and was wondering if anyone could give me any information about the seal.

[image]

Comment: iboth of thems say 文景 maybe it is the artist's name

Comment: I agree [文景](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%96%87%E6%99%AF/10049521) is most likely the artist's name, but it sounds very similar to a famous Chinese historical term (西汉文帝与景帝的并称。两帝相继，社会比较安定富裕，史称“文景之治)